"Causality property" of Green's functions for the wave equation
Let $G(t,\vec{x})$ be a Green's function for the (unit-wavespeed) wave equation on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ with coordinates $(t,\vec{x})$; i.e., $(\partial_t^2 - \nabla_x^2)G = \delta(t) \delta^n(\vec{x})$.
Let us suppose that for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\lim_{\Vert\vec{x}\Vert\to\infty} G(t,\vec{x}) = 0$.
I would like to show that in general (e.g. irrespective of the dimension $n$ and of the particular choice of Green's function $G$)
the Green's function must satisfy the following "causality property":
$$
G(t,\vec{x}) = 0 \text{ for } \Vert\vec{x}\Vert >\vert t\vert \,.
$$
However, I'm not sure how to approach proving this, hopefully by some method that circumvents the full calculation of the Green's function (for arbitrary $n$). Would anyone have a suggestion for how to approach this proof, or for a reference that discusses this?

By the spatial symmetry of the problem as posed, maybe look at radial solutions. This’ll give you a pde in $t$ and $r$ from which the method of characteristics  for second order systems might deliver the result you’re looking for.

The classical representation of Green's functions for the wave equation for $n=1,2,3$ are obtained by Fourier transform methods. You can find these pretty easily just by Googling. I believe that they require some nasty integrals as $n$ increases so it may not be possible to get analytic expressions for all $n$

@whpowell96 Sure, but I believe there should be some elegant way to prove the causality property without using the full analytic expression for the Green's functions for every $n$. The causality condition seems like a simple consequence of the intuitive fact that waves cannot spread faster than their wavespeed

@Aruralreader Thank you! I don't have a lot of background in PDEs but I will look into the idea you suggested. However, I'd really like to know of a reference that explicitly looks at topics like "causality properties" of wave equations and similar PDEs

@I.A.S.Tambe: I’d bet a goodly sum you’ll find it in the second, maybe first though, volume of Courant and Hilbert.

Doesn't a finite domain of dependence imply that the Green's function has compact support for each $t$? If you don't actually want to prove these facts about the Green's function directly then you can pull from other properties of the wave equation that are easier to work with and just translate them to properties of the Green's function

@whpowell96 I'd like to avoid calculating the expression for the Green's function in a region that isn't relevant to the causality property, for just proving the causality property. Also, certainly the Green's function having compact support for each $t$ isn't sufficient to prove the causality property. Maybe I will look into other properties of the wave equation, but I'm primarily interested in using the causality of the Green's function to prove properties of the wave equation, as opposed to the other way around. I acknowledge there might be some more efficient approach though
